# find documents in mongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a mongo document structure like this:

```
{
    "competition_id" : 421,
    "matches" :
        [
            "m_id" : 1234,
            "players":
                [
                    {
                        "id" : 52165267,
                        "name" : "...",
                        "surname" : "...",
                        ..
                    }
                ],
            "date" : 2012-10-12,
            ...
        ]
}
```

I want to be able to find (return) all documents that (for a given $player_id), the player doesn`t exists in "matches.players.id"s array. I tried the '$nin' operator but with no success.

Thanks

Comment: I doubt it's possible with operators. You have to write javascript code for filtering.

Comment: Please, show how you've tried to use '$nin'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly in 'matches' replace your '[' with '{'

I tried your sample document and the below query works fine for me:

```
db.collection_name.find( {"matches.players.id":{'$nin':[5]}} )
```